# R - Create a Position Frequency Matrix

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I have some sequences of nucleobases of DNA and I want to make a Position Frequency Matrix. Should I put every sequence in a row of a simple matrix and then run through every column and count how many A, C, G, T I have? Or is there an easier and more simple way?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a short sequence and the desired output?

Comment: Did you have a look into bioconductor especially biostring? See https://support.bioconductor.org/p/56424/

Comment: More specifically, I have to load a dataset with noucleobases and I have to check how much similar is every seventh of them with a motif which I have. If there are 0 or 1 different letters, I want to keep the sequence. In the end I want to make a Position Frequency Matrix with the sequences I got.

Comment: @Linus I am not allowed to use the function to create the matrix.

Comment: @Johanna So this is an assignment. Please provide what you tried so far? Including some example data. Stackoverflow will not code it for you, but may help if you struggle.

Comment: @Linus, I am thinking how to solve this problem. My problem is that while I keep checking for similar sequences, I want to keep the old in a matrix. So, I have to initialize a matrix, but I dont know its size. And I think it's a little complexity and perhaps there is another way.

Comment: Are your sequences always the same length? If could create a vector from each sequence, and later combined them using do.call(rbind, list_of_sequence_vectors)

Comment: @Linus, well I found a solution, thank you very much for helping.